# Date Time Picker Custom Format

Tags: c#

this is my code:

```
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;

dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:MM";

dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Hi I use Custom Format for my  `dateTimePicker` until do not show second  but its format hide AM/PM in  dateTimePicker how can show AM/PM in this format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just add `tt` for `AM/PM`.

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm tt"
```

and it should be `mm` for minutes.

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)